# Internet Explorer doesnot login to website of remote desktop is not opened

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ie9

I am writing a simple script that will log in to a website, I am trying to run it through Jenkins job on a remote desktop, I have placed my code on GIT Hub and configured Jenkins to run test.

My application supports only Internet Explorer, So I have to run test on IE(9.0) with webdriver 2.44.
If I run my test through Jenkins with Remote Desktop opened it works fine, but when I try to run the test without opening remote desktop, it opens the IE and navigate to Login page, set focus to "user-id" but thereafter doing nothing.

can someone please suggest something?

Regards
VS

Comment: Can you connect with something other than remote desktop, such as VNC? Remote desktop takes control of the remote system's GUI, and when closed the remote system is locked (if you exit the session) or logged off. If your application isn't headless, not having remote desktop open will interfere with it unless you're using something like a VNC client to connect/view/monitor progress.

Comment: Hi Kate, Thanks for your reply,Do you mean if i monitor my application(non headless) through VNC client i wont face this issue?I am running my application (from local browser) through Jenkins, which runs the application on remote machine

Comment: Correct - I've found that VNC Client doesn't interfere with the machine's session the way Remote Desktop does. You will need to make sure you have a logged in session on the remote machine, but other than that you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description that you had mentioned in the question it should work properly except if you are not using something that would require the remote connection/machine to be in with-display state. Like the conditions:

1. If your using keyboard events like ,  or any keyboard events then your script will not work until unless machine display is not in open state.

If you are not using any keyboard events then there may be some user security/permission issue with IE. It would be better to share the error logs so that it will be easy to troubleshoot the issue. In [QA testing services](https://www.qasource.com/) you should perform the automation on the basis of assumptions that how script will behave in different machines and different security permissions. And its the logs that could tell the real reason of failures.